# Can we check size of Hive tables? If so, how?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql, hue

I have **many tables** in **Hive** and suspect size of these tables are causing space issues on cluster. Is there a way to check the size of Hive tables in one shot? If so, how? We are able to use the Tblproperties, or tbldescription. But it is useful for one table. it is tedious to run the same command for each table. I am looking for a approach to run a command and get all required info. The output should be including below fields:
Database name:
Table name:
totalSize: 
numFiles:
numPartitions: 
numRows:
rawDataSize:
P.S: previous approach is applicable for one table.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no single command to achieve the results you're looking.

You can write a custom script

1. Get list of databases  `hive -e "SHOW DATABASES" > db_list_file`
2. Iterate through the list of dbs to get all tables in respective database(s) `hive -e "SHOW TABLES" > table_list_file`
3. Run `DESCRIBE EXTENDED ${db}.${tble}` on all the tables, parse the output to get path of the table
4. If all files are in HDFS you can get the size `hdfs dfs -du -s <list of hdfs files>`

Hope this helps